# Using support library version lower than compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, sdk, version

I work with android studio and in build.gradle file some dependencies are underlined in red. The message is :

This support library should not use a different version (25) than the compileSdkVersion (26)

I know how to resolve this (just use the same version) but my question is : what will happen if I leave it that way ? Will I have problems knowing that my config is :

- targetSdkVersion 26
- compileSdkVersion 26

Thank you for your answer and have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Onik ! But I did the build with this in my dependencies : compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app may run fine. Or it may crash. In short, mismatching support library and compile versions may/will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you scottt ! But if the application is well tested, is it still possible that the application crash (caused by versions mismatching) ?

Comment: You should always match the support libraries to the compiled SDK, there's no reason why shouldn't want to anyway. Its very possible, that an older support library running on a higher targetted SDK could cause a crash in some unexpected way under certain circumstances

Comment: Thank's, I understand. I ask this question because we use RoboGuice in our app and it is not supported anymore. If I change the support library version from 25 to 26 I have a lot of compilation errors. That why I try to find an alternative but in fact, I have no choice.

Comment: It may be better for you to lower your compile and target SDKs down to 25 so that you can keep everything in sync.